# unrecognized arguments when executing script via crontab

Tags: bash, cron

I have my crontab set up as follows (this is inside a docker container).

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
5 * * * * bash /usr/local/bin/process-logs > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/
```

The `/usr/local/bin/process-logs` is designed to expose some MongoDB logs using `mtools` to a simple web server.

The problematic part of the script is fairly simple. `raw_name` is `archive_name` without the file extension.

```
    aws s3 cp "s3://${s3_bucket}/${file_name}" "${archive_name}" 
    gunzip "${archive_name}"

    mlogvis --no-browser "${raw_name}"
```

If I manually run the command as specified in the crontab config above

```
bash /usr/local/bin/process-logs > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

It all works as expected (this is the expected output from `mlogvis`)

```
...
copying /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mtools/data/index.html to /some/path/mongod.log-20190313-1552456862.html
...
```

When the script gets triggered via crontab it throws the following error

```
usage: mlogvis [-h] [--version] [--no-progressbar] [--no-browser] [--out OUT]
               [--line-max LINE_MAX]
mlogvis: error: unrecognized arguments: mongod.log-20190313-1552460462
```

The `mlogvis` command that caused the following error (actual values not parameters)

```
mlogvis --no-browser "mongod.log-20190313-1552460462"
```

Again if I run this command myself it all works as expected.

mlogvis: http://blog.rueckstiess.com/mtools/mlogvis.html

I don't believe this to be an issue with the file not having correct permissions or not existing as `mlogvis` produces a different error in these conditions. I've also tested with removing '-' from the file name thinking it might be trying to parse these as arguments but it made no difference.

I know cron execution doesn't have the same execution environment as the user I tested the script as. I've set the PATH to be the same as the user and when the container starts up I execute `env >> /etc/environment` so all the environment vars and properly set.

Does anyone know of a way to debug this or has anyone encountered similar? All other components of the script are functioning except `mlogvis` which is core to the purpose of this job.

Summary of what I've tried as a fix:

- Set environment and PATH for cron execution to be the same as the user I tested the script as
- Replace `-` in file name(s) to see if it was parsing the parts as arguments
- hardcode a filename with full permissions to see if it was permissions related
- Manually run the script -> this works
- Manually run the mlogvis command in isolation -> this works

Comment: A `2` is missing from the end of your crontab line; this might cause the script to make a different decision later? (Probably just a paste error in the question though)

Answer (score 0):

try to load `/home/user/.bash_profile` before executing script and try again. I suspect that you have missing  PATH or other environment variable which is not set.

```
source /home/user/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post your complete script, because while executing via crontab, 
you have to be sure your `raw_name` variable was properly created. As 
it seems to depend on `archive_name`, posting some more context can 
help us to help you.

In any case, if you are using bash, you can try something like :

```
aws s3 cp "s3://${s3_bucket}/${file_name}" "${archive_name}" 
gunzip "${archive_name}"

# here you have to be sure that archive_name is correct
raw_name_2=${archive_name%%.*}

mlogvis --no-browser "${raw_name_2}"
```

It is not going to solve your issue, but probably will take you closer to the right path.